# Исполнить код на машине с помощью javascript?

Tags: javascript

Увидел в [статье](http://habrahabr.ru/post/254777/#comment_8358287) на хабре это :[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Какой код имеется ввиду? И это документированные возможности или же какой-то тип взлома?

Просто сейчас я использую java applet на странице сайта, который вещает данные по udp на нужный порт, чтобы пользователи могли подключится к серверу из другой программы(не моей) просто перейдя на нужную страницу сайта. Но это решение не очень популярное, так как у пользователя должна быть установлена java и applet добавлен в исключения. А решение с отдельной программой, тоже не подходит, так как им снова придется качать что-то, а это потеря ощутимой аудитории.
 То есть, цель чтобы пользователь получил это вещание на своем компьютере без установки дополнительно ПО. Не важно, если ему придется подтверждать какие-то действия в самом браузере, главное чтобы ему не нужно было вручную устанавливать и запускать.

Comment: http://learn.javascript.ru/websockets - возможно, стоит прочитать про это.

Comment: Судя по всему у вас два вопроса: про код на машине и про java applet на странице, поэтому их стоит разделить на два отдельных вопроса. По первому - а о чем вообще речь шла? Может "машина" - это браузер клиента? А может и про js-приложение говорили (в 8 винде они вроде без браузера запускаются, хотя деталей не знаю) По второму - а если flash использовать? Он практически у всех есть